# How can i sample process?

Tags: c#

i have application who use specific process during running and i want to sample the process and check if the process crash in order to find the specific file who cause the crash, how can i sample process from my computer and also check if the process id changed ?

Comment: **what have you tried?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the process you want by using Process.GetProcesses Method -
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8b2hzk8(v=vs.110).aspx

Then it's pretty simple since you will have Process Class that will contain all data you want including ProcessID